# VBA Compile Error: Object Required (getting greys at this point)

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Some background on myself: I have done some simple programming in my life but just C++ and simple VBA.  I am not very familiar with VBA syntax and I'm trying.

I'm working on a functions to compare 2 sets of cells.  If the cells are the same then `False` is returned and `True` for not being the same.  Problem is I cannot get my if statement to work in order to create my count which will eventually give me my `True` or `False`

The line I'm having problems and receiving a run-time error 424: object required.

```
If firstCaseVal Is secondCaseVal Then
    k = k + 1
End If
```

Here is the complete function:

```
Function histMisMatch() As Boolean
Dim matchCountRows As Integer
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim k As Integer
Dim firstCaseVal As Variant, secondCaseVal As Variant, firstCase As Variant, secondCase As Variant        
    With ws2
        matchCountRows = Columns(1).Find(Asset, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    End With

    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

    k = 0

    For i = 1 To 9
        firstCase = ws2.Cells(matchCountRows, i).Value
        firstCaseVal = firstCase

        With ws3
        Set secondCase = ws3.Columns(i).Find(firstCase, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set secondCaseVal = secondCase            
        End With

        If firstCaseVal Is secondCaseVal Then
            k = k + 1
        End If            
    Next        

    If k = 9 Then
        histMisMatch = False
    Else
        histMisMatch = True
    End If        
End Function
```

Code with changes made but still received run-time error 91 on the if statement

```
Function histMisMatch() As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim matchCountRows As Integer
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim k As Integer
Dim firstCaseVal As Variant, secondCaseVal As Variant, firstCase As Variant, secondCase As Variant

    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

    With ws2
        matchCountRows = .Columns(1).Find(Asset, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    End With 

    k = 0

    For i = 1 To 9
        firstCase = ws2.Cells(matchCountRows, i).Value
        firstCaseVal = firstCase

        With ws3
        Set secondCase = ws3.Columns(i).Find(firstCase, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set secondCaseVal = secondCase
        End With

        If firstCaseVal = secondCaseVal Then
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next


    If k = 9 Then
        histMisMatch = False
    Else
        histMisMatch = True
    End If        
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using find() to locate a cell with a specific value, then comparing the value in that cell with the searched-for value, which of course would always match as long as there was a hit.

Instead you can just test for

```
If Not secondCase Is Nothing Then
```

since Find() returns `Nothing` if it doesn't find a match (and that's what's causing your error "object variable or with block variable not set").

**EDIT**  - some suggested changes:

```
Function histMisMatch() As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim matchCountRows As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim firstCase As Variant

    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

    matchCountRows = ws2.Columns(1).Find(Asset, lookat:=xlWhole).Row

    For i = 1 To 9
        firstCase = ws2.Cells(matchCountRows, i).Value
        If ws3.Columns(i).Find(firstCase, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            histMisMatch = True
            Exit Function 'you can stop looking here, since one value was not found...
        End If
    Next
    'got here if no missing values...
    histMisMatch = False

End Function
```

Comment: No they do not always match... it is a check to see if the value of the cells in the desired row from column 1 through 9 are already there and if they are then they are not copied and disregarded, however if they are not present in `ws3` then they are copied into `ws3`

Comment: Not that it solved the run-time error I was getting it is a more simple and elegant solution to my problem.  thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

IF you are trying to compare them use an = instead of Is

```
If firstCaseVal = secondCaseVal Then
    k = k + 1
End If
```

Comment: I have tried this before but I get this error:
Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your code:

```
Dim i as integer 'Dim all your variables

Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Set the sheet before using it

With ws2 'You need to add a . before what you write in a With that is to be preceded with the With argument
    matchCountRows = .Columns(1).Find(Asset, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
'What is Asset? If it is a string, you need to write it like "Asset"
End With

If firstCaseVal = secondCaseVal Then 'Use = to compare, not Is
     k = k + 1
End If
```

I believe it will work if you make these changes.

Comment: adding a "." to matchCountRows gives a compile error.  Removed the "." and now the if statement with an "=" gives run-time error 91: object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: See my edit. I think the use of Asset is the problem.

Comment: I changed the placement of the period too. You want to use the columns of ws2, so the period is before columns.

Comment: Asset is a user form label which is just a valued passed to it from another userform

Comment: Numeric values, like strings, are not set. You'd write SecondCaseVal = secondcase. Not Set secondcaseVal = secondcase. I suggest you dim the Values as integers/long/doubles to avoid confusion (but not necessary). I think the program considers it as a Range object because you set it equal to the cell in which you found your info.